# PHP AMQP Consume() fork to do actual work

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm looking to have a PHP script that consumes (using the PECL AMQP module) from a RabbitMQ queue and then forks off to do the actual work.

I've got code @ https://gist.github.com/giggsey/6666e67bb0e090eeb5f0

But when I run it, I get:

> 11296 Key: USER.12392   ObjectLength: 74 Forked 11296 at 2013-03-19
>
> 14:16:22 11277 ack() PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>
> 'AMQPConnectionException' with message 'Connection reset by peer' in tmp/forking.php:10
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 tmp/forking.php(10): AMQPQueue->consume(Array)
>
> 1 tmp/forking.php(102): test->run()
>
> 2 {main}   thrown in tmp/forking.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'AMQPConnectionException' with message
> 'Connection reset by peer' in tmp/forking.php on line 10
>
> AMQPConnectionException: Connection reset by peer in tmp/forking.php on line 10
>
> Call Stack:
>
> ```
> 0.0006     665008   1. {main}() tmp/forking.php:0
>
> 0.0007     665456   2. test->run() tmp/forking.php:102
>
> 0.0359     670504   3. AMQPQueue->consume() tmp/forking.php:10
> ```

Comment: Did you try this without the fork stuff?

Comment: @mzedeler Yeah, it works fine without the forking.

Comment: You are running from the CLI?

Comment: @Bubba Yup. PHP 5.3 with Peck AMQP 1.0.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You fork after the connection is made, which means the child is inheriting the connection, such that the parent and all children end up using the same connection, and if any child exits (which automagically closes the connection) or closes the connection, the parent and all siblings suddenly discover they no longer have a connection.

So instead of using:

```
$connection->connect();
```

Use the less documented:

```
$connection->pconnect();
```

Which will provide a persistent connect, such that when the forked child does close the connection, the parent automagically reopens it.

Comment: Duh. Reading is essential. It appears that the children are likely killing your connection though. I'll play with it when I have some time - it's a fun puzzle.

Comment: Aight, I wrote a functioning example and updated the submitted answer, hope that works for you!

Comment: I think I misdirected you with my question. What I was trying to do was have the consume in the parent, and then it will fork off a child and do some potential heavy work.

Comment: Yer killing me! ;-)  So you want to run a script, in that script you want to instantiate a queue that consumes ... then you want the call back to fork (blocking the parent) until some work is done, at which pont the child dies, and the parent script continues to monitor the queue for something else to consume?

Comment: Correct :) Similar to how php-resque (and I think normal resque) works, but using Rabbit

Comment: I think I fixed it, I used your script, just change $connection->connect(); to $connection->pconnect();

Before that change, I would could reproduce your error, after that change, it is working fine for me. If you confirm, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm happy with that. If you update your answer, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: That was fun! Thanks for letting me play.